# ZSH shell script loops MANY times?

Tags: zsh, wkhtmltopdf, automator

So I want to convert these blogposts to PDF using `wkhtmltopdf`

On MacOS in automator I set up a WorkFlow: **GET SPECIFIED TEXT** > **EXTRACT URLS FROM TEXT** > **RUN SHELL SCRIPT** (shell: /bin/zsh, pass input: as arguments)

```
#!/bin/zsh
# url example: "https://www.somewordpressblog.com/2022/12/16/some-post-title/"

i=1
for url in "$@"
do  
    title1=${url[(ws:/:)6]}                 # split with delimiter / sixth part
    title2=${(U)title1//-/ }                # replace all hypens with spaces and capitalize
    title3="$i. - "                         # prefix add numbers
    title4=".pdf"                           # suffix add .PDF extension
    title5="${title3}${title2}${title4}"    # join everything 
    
    /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --disable-javascript --print-media-type $url $title5
    ((i+=1))
done
```

The files got downloaded, but for a test with only 2 URL's there was like 2 minutes waiting and the RESULTS from the Schell Script showed me 84 items!!
I am counting 14 DONES from the wkhtmltopdf output.

What is wrong with this loop? Do I need to implement something to wait for the loop to continue or something? And How?

Any code suggestions welcome as well, first day with ZSH..

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as "Bash/ZSH". `bash` is one shell, `zsh` another. You are using `zsh`, period.

Comment: How did you execute the script? You might want to add something like `print $url` to the top of the loop so you can see what (and how many) arguments the script *actually* receives, rather than which ones you *think* it is receiving.

Comment: I just run the loop without code for 2 URL's `i=1; for url in "$@"; do print $url; done` Guess what, 4-6-12-16-20 up to 32 items, very inconsistent !!

Comment: *What* comes up more than twice? Please be specific and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is it `wkhtmltopdf` that's generating the additional output? Is your calling script breaking up the URL's based on shell tokens (`;` or `&`, etc)? You could use a simple debugging `print` inside the loop to prove how many times the loop is looping.

Comment: I attached an image, as you can see, this time with 2 url's, 10 items! WTF?

Comment: The shell parts of your code are very simple and fast; all the work, and thus all the delay, lives inside this `wkhtmltopdf` tool.

Comment: And to echo what chepner told you -- take the bash tag off this question. You should only tag for the shell you _actually use_; zsh is not bash, and also is not compatible with bash. The code given in the question is (as far as I know) correct for zsh but would be badly buggy if run in bash, because they're _not the same shell_, and the languages are different.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you reproduce this problem _without_ automator? The easy way to figure out whether you have a zsh problem or an automator problem is to just pass your two arguments _direct to your script_ at the prompt.

Comment: You still aren't indicating how you are executing this script (via Automator, apparently) with "one" argument. It's quite possible that your script *itself* is being called multiple times, rather than once with multiple arguments. (The script as show would *not* "multiply" a single argument the way you think it is.)

Comment: There is something wrong with the loop, see attached image, for only 2 URL's I get them printed 10 times... sometimes 14 or 8 or 12 or 16 and so on. Why is that?? Is the loop code correct?

Comment: Nothing in that image suggests you are passing 2, or any particular number of, URLs.

Comment: I changed the picture, so you can see the URL's, thanks

Comment: If I do `for x (1 2 3); do echo $x; done` I get some random results 15, 24, 30, 9 and so on...

Comment: Again, can you cause _any_ of these problems if you stop using automator and just call your script directly? (If not, that'll let you ask a narrower, more specific question that's only about automator; if so, it'll let you ask a narrow, specific question that's only about zsh).